# append epoch time to a url

Tags: php, javascript, get, append, epoch

Hi I'm trying to append the current epoch time to a url, so onclick it would get a page from the url structured as the following :

http://example.com/grab.php?ans_id=value1&d=epoch time

So for example:

http://example.com/grab.php?ans_id=254&d=1308264776271

I can get the epoch time generated in javascript but cant get it appended to the url :(

any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean you can get it generated in JavaScript but can't append it to the URL? What language are you using? And can you give us the code you tried, so we can try seeing what's wrong with it?

Comment: Like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/JeLwQ/

Comment: well what's currently working is this : [code pasted on slexy](http://slexy.org/view/s2H7RujspH) but i would want this to send the exact current epoch time and not the one of the last page load .

Comment: @james yeah, (thnx for that allready btw :D) now i would  just want to trigger going to this with the click of a link ...

ps is there a way for me to give karma points or something here ? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.  It takes the href of the link you click on, adds the current epoch stamp and sends you to that page.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeLwQ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this code in your JavaScript file and then call `updateEpoch()` to set the epoch in the URL:

```
function updateEpoch(){
    if(/&d=(.*)/.test(location.href)){
        location = location.href.replace(/&d=(.*)/,"&d="+(new Date().getTime()));
    }else{
        location.href += "&d="+(new Date().getTime());
    }
}
```

Ad@m

Comment: thanks a lot ^_^
i didn't expect to get help this fast,
you guys are awesome :D
thanks again for helping me with this,
hope i can help some people on here aswell in the future :)